# server crash issue in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a set of `api` and I am posting the data to the database, in response I am fetching the required response in `json` form from the database. The issue that I am facing is ,when I post data for first time it will get posted and for second time my server will get crashed and gives **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**  I don't know why I am getting this error. Please let me know where I am going wrong

```
router.post('/addcustomerskills', function(req,res) {
    var skill = req.body.skill;
    var skill_id = req.body.skill_id;
    var skill_name = req.body.skill_name;
    var rating = req.body.rating;
    var response = {};

    if (typeof skill ==='undefined') {
        response.token = '2ewerr4';
        response.success = false,
        response.skill = null;
        response.mssg = 'fields cannot be empty';
        res.json(response);
    } else {
        var j =1;
        for (i in skill) {
            var skillObj=skill[i];  
            db.query('INSERT into skill(skill_id,skill_name,rating) values(?,?,?)', [skillObj.skill_id, skillObj.skill_name, skillObj.rating], function(error, rows) {
                if (error) {
                    res.json(error);
                } else {        
                    db.query('select id,skill_id,skill_name,rating FROM skills WHERE skill_id = ?', [skillObj.skill_id], function(error, rows) {
                        response.success = true,
                        //response.skills = rows;
                        response.skills = skill;
                        response.mssg = 'Successfully Updated';
                        if(j === 1) {
                            j = 0;
                            res.json(response);
                        }           
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. when you send a second request, you've more than one skills right ? 2. is skillId set to be `unique` in your `db table`

Comment: can you tell me this is the only code you are using or you have shorten the code to add here.

Comment: this is the only code i am using  @Himanshusharma

Comment: that's  not the problem. Suppose if i there is any error in query , app is getting crashed.  @UsmanRana

Comment: see the change give below

Answer (score 0):

Since, `db.query()` works in async way you're experiencing this issue.

So, try this

```
router.post('/addcustomerskills', function(req,res) {
    var skill = req.body.skill;
    var skill_id = req.body.skill_id;
    var skill_name = req.body.skill_name;
    var rating = req.body.rating;
    var response = {};

    if (typeof skill ==='undefined') {
        response.token = '2ewerr4';
        response.success = false,
        response.skill = null;
        response.mssg = 'fields cannot be empty';
        res.json(response);
    } else {
        var i, count = 0;
        // var j = 1;
        var result = [];
        for (i in skill) {
            count++;
            var skillObj=skill[i];  
            db.query('INSERT into skill(skill_id,skill_name,rating) values(?,?,?)', [skillObj.skill_id, skillObj.skill_name, skillObj.rating], function(error, rows) {
                if (error) {
                    result.push(response);
                    response = {};
                    if(count == skill.length){
                        res.json(result);
                    }
                } else {        
                    db.query('select id,skill_id,skill_name,rating FROM skills WHERE skill_id = ?', [skillObj.skill_id], function(innerError, innerRows) {
                        response.success = true,
                        //response.skills = innerRows;
                        response.skills = skill;
                        response.mssg = 'Successfully Updated';

                        // I don't understand why you have used the variable 'j', so I commented it
                        // if(j === 1) {
                        //     j = 0;
                        //     res.json(response);
                        // }           

                        result.push(response);
                        response = {};
                        if(count == skill.length){
                            res.json(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And also, you should use a seperate variable name when you're nesting the `db.query()`

Comment: should i use it inside the loop or out-side the loop

Comment: just now i implemented, but again my server got crashed

Comment: @SRK Just now I have edited my post. So, try it out!

Answer (score 0):

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

has simple meaning that you are sending res multiple time.

@SRK the error here is this

You have `for loop` in which you are sending `res` back every time when you query to database .

Send response back after the for loop finish .

```
router.post('/addcustomerskills', function(req,res) {
    var skill = req.body.skill;
    var skill_id = req.body.skill_id;
    var skill_name = req.body.skill_name;
    var rating = req.body.rating;
    var response = {};

    if (typeof skill ==='undefined') {
        response.token = '2ewerr4';
        response.success = false,
        response.skill = null;
        response.mssg = 'fields cannot be empty';
        res.json(response);
    } else {
        var j =1;
        for (i in skill) {
            var skillObj=skill[i];  
            db.query('INSERT into skill(skill_id,skill_name,rating) values(?,?,?)', [skillObj.skill_id, skillObj.skill_name, skillObj.rating], function(error, rows) {
                if (error) {

                } else {        
                    db.query('select id,skill_id,skill_name,rating FROM skills WHERE skill_id = ?', [skillObj.skill_id], function(error, rows) {
                        response.success = true,
                        //response.skills = rows;
                        response.skills = skill;
                        response.mssg = 'Successfully Updated';
                        if(j === 1) {
                            j = 0;

                        }           
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    res.json({"message":"what you want to send"});
    }
});
```

If you want to handle crush add this in your main node.js file

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log("error",error);
});
```

Comment: i tried this technique, but still i faced the same issue

Comment: i implemented your technique, but i am getting empty resopnse

Comment: check out the error and solve that , the error will print in the new block . code change check. `console.log("error",error);` .